# Testing whether an executable can be run on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation, executable, test

In my Ubuntu packages, I install a hook with a one liner script:

```
if test -x /usr/bin/snapsignal
then
    /usr/bin/snapsignal "snapmanagerdaemon/DPKGUPDATE hook_action=\"$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION\""
fi
```

(broken original line on multiple lines so it's easier to read here)

The problem is that `/usr/bin/snapsignal` uses libraries which once in a while get replaced (i.e. old package gets removed just before the new version gets installed). When that happens, the `snapsignal` tool fails running.

The signal is not super important, so I don't mind if it doesn't run. What I'm wondering is whether there is a simple command to know that a library is missing and thus the tool won't run.

As we can see, I try to verify that the `snapsignal` file is an executable, but that only means the `x` flag is set on it. Not that it can indeed be executed.

I also tried `ldd /usr/bin/snapsignal`. That shows the missing library, but it still `exit(0)` so it's useless to test whether I can indeed execute that command. Any other idea?

I would prefer to avoid using `set +e` to ignore the errors altogether because there could be other errors and I want to catch them.

Comment: Is there some reason parsing `ldd`'s output (`ldd | grep 'not found'`) won't work?

Comment: @drewbenn, I'm thinking that may not be a good long term solution?

Comment: @drewbenn, yes; I don't see why the output of ldd wouldn't change over time. Actually, if you run on a system with a language other than English, it may output that sentence in that language ("pas trouvé") and my script fails.

Comment: @AlexisWilke or it mayn't (the dynamic linker is yet not gettext'isized). But anyways, let me tell you about `LC_ALL=C cmd ...` ;-)

Comment: You should just exec the thing and handle the errors instead of complicating you with that check. Or if you don't care about the errors: `/usr/bin/snapsignal || :`.